# Smallest missing number at any point in time in a stream of positive numbers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We are processing a stream of positive integers. At any point in time, we can be asked a query to which the answer is the smallest positive number that we have not seen yet.

One can assume two APIs.

```
void processNext(int val)
int getSmallestNotSeen()
```

We can assume the numbers to be bounded by the range [1,10^6]. Let this range be N.

Here is my solution.

> Let's take an array of size 10^6. 
>  
>  Whenever processNext(val) is called we mark the array[val] to be 1. We make a sum segment tree on this array. This will be a point update in the segment tree. 
>  Whenever getSmallestNotSeen() is called I find the smallest index j such that sum [1..j] is less than j. I find j using binary search.
>  processNext(val) -> O(1) 
>  getSmallestNotSeen() -> O((logN)^2)

I was thinking maybe if there was something more optimal. Or the above solution can be improved.

Comment: When you limit N to 10^6, it does not really make much sense to talk about time complexity.

Comment: It is trivial to read N whereever 10^6 is written in the problem statement; so of course it makes sense to talk about asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @kaya3, I am referring to the explicit statement that the range is bounded. If so, then...

Comment: I know you are referring to that; there is nothing else you could have been referring to. My point stands; use your imagination and read "N" where you see "10^6", and it makes sense to talk about asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a map of id - > node (nodes of a doubly-linked list) and initialize for 10^6 nodes, each pointing to its neighbors. Initialize the min to one.

processNext(val): check if the node exists. If it does, delete it and point its neighbors at each other. If the node you delete has no left neighbor (i.e. was smallest), update the min to be the right neighbor.

getSmallestNotSeen(): return the min

The preprocessing is linear time and linear memory. Everything after that is constant time.

Comment: @trincot That's what the map is for. Constant time lookup. Keys are initialized to 1, 2, ..., 10^6.

Comment: That's quite a space requirement.

Comment: It's O(N) space, which is asymptotically optimal for this problem. The OP's solution also uses O(N) space. That said, the keys in the map are a contiguous range of integers so you might as well use an array instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool array[10^6] = {false, false, ... }
int min = 1

void processNext(int val) {
    array[val] = true      // A
    while (array[min])     // B
        min++              // C
}

int getSmallestNotSeen() {
    return min
}
```

Time complexity:

- processNext: amortised `O(1)`
- getSmallestNotSeen: `O(1)`

Analysis:

If `processNext` is invoked `k` times and `n` is the highest value stored in `min` (which could be returned in `getSmallestNotSeen`), then:

- the line `A` will be executed exactly `k` times,
- the line `B` will be executed exactly `k + n` times, and
- the line `C` will be executed exactly `n` times.

Additionally, `n` will never be greater than `k`, because for `min` to reach `n` there needs to be a continous range of `n` `true`'s in the array, and there can be only `k` `true`'s in the array in total. Therefore, line `B` can be executed at most `2 * k` times and line `C` at most `k` times.

Space complexity:

Instead of an array it is possible to use a HashMap without any additional changes in the pseudocode (non-existing keys in the HashMap should evaluate to `false`). Then the space complexity is `O(k)`. Additionally, you can prune keys smaller than `min`, thus saving space in some cases:

```
HashMap<int,bool> map
int min = 1

void processNext(int val) {
    if (val < min)
        return
    map.put(val, true)
    while (map.get(min) = true)
        map.remove(min)
        min++
}

int getSmallestNotSeen() {
    return min
}
```

This pruning technique might be most effective if the stream values increase steadily.

Comment: Nice solution, +1. Would be worth explaining why `processNext` is O(1) amortised.

Comment: I don't think the analysis of this is correct; A will be executed `k` times, and `B` will be executed at most `2*k` times because `array[min]` can only be true for `k` distinct values of `min`, and it will be false at most `k` times too. This matters because `n` could be large compared to `k`.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that `k` is much larger than `n`. I've assumed that repeating values are allowed.

Comment: The conclusion is still correct - it's O(1) amortised because A, B and C run at most `k`, `2*k` and `k` times respectively when the total number of queries is `k`, so that 1, 2 and 1 per query respectively. The size of `n` relative to `k` doesn't matter if you do the analysis this way.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, I've edited the analysis according to your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

In case the number of `processNext` calls (i.e. the length of the stream) is fairly small compared with the range of *N*, then space usage could be limited by storing consecutive *ranges* of numbers, instead of all possible individual numbers. This is also interesting when *N* could be a much larger range, like [1, 2<sup>64</sup>-1]

#### Data structure

I would suggest a binary search tree with such [start, end] ranges as elements, and self-balancing (like AVL, red-black, ...).

#### Algorithm

Initialise the tree with one (root) node: [1, Infinity]

Whenever a new value `val` is pulled with `processNext`, find the range [start, end] that includes `val`, using binary search.

If the range has size 1 (and thus only contains `val`), perform a deletion of that node (according to the tree rules)

Else if `val` is a bounding value of the range, then just update the range in that node, excluding `val`.

Otherwise split the range into two. Update the node with one of the two ranges (decide by the balance information) and let the other range sift down to a new leaf (and rebalance if needed).

In the tree maintain a reference to the node having the least start value. Only when this node gets deleted during `processNext` it will need a traversal up or down the tree to find the next (in order) node. When the node splits (see above) and it is decided the put the lower part in a new leaf, the reference needs to be updated to that leaf.

The `getSmallestNotSeen` function will return the start-value from that least-range node.

#### Time & Space Complexity

The space complexity is *O(S)*, where *S* is the length of the stream

The time complexity of `processNext` is *O(log(S))*

The time complexity of `getSmallestNotSeen` is *O(1)*

The best case space and time complexity is *O(1)*. Such a best case occurs when the stream has consecutive integers (increasing or decreasing)

Comment: Interesting solution. I don't exactly follow why `getSmallestNotSeen` can return the lower bound from the root node; if it's a binary search tree, isn't the lowest element stored in the left-most node, not the root node?

Comment: Indeed, I updated the text to indicate that a reference to the node with the least range must be maintained. This will have the same time complexity as the other tasks in `processNext`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution takes O(N) space to hold the array and the sum segment tree, and O(N) time to initialise them; then O(1) and O(log² N) for the two queries. It seems pretty clear that you can't do better than O(N) space in the long run to keep track of which numbers are "seen" so far, if there are going to be a lot of queries.

However, a different data structure can improve on the query times. Here are three ideas:

---

### Self-balancing binary search tree

Initialise the tree to contain every number from 1 to N; this can be done in O(N) time by building the tree from the leaves up; the leaves have all the odd numbers, then they're joined by all the numbers which are 2 mod 4, then those are joined by the numbers which are 4 mod 8, and so on. The tree takes O(N) space.

- `processNext` is implemented by removing the number from the tree in O(log N) time.
- `getSmallestNotSeen` is implemented by finding the left-most node in O(log N) time.

This is an improvement if `getSmallestNotSeen` is called many times, but if `getSmallestNotSeen` is rarely called then your solution is better because it does `processNext` in O(1) rather than O(log N).

---

### Doubly-linked list

Initialise a doubly-linked list containing the numbers 1 to N in order, and create an array of size N holding pointers to each node. This takes O(N) space and is done in O(N) time. Initialise a variable holding a cached minimum value to be 1.

- `processNext` is implemented by looking up the corresponding list node in the array, and deleting it from the list. If the deleted node has no predecessor, update the cached minimum value to be the value held by the successor node. This is O(1) time.
- `getSmallestNotSeen` is implemented by returning the cached minimum, in O(1) time.

This is also an improvement, and is strictly better asymptotically, although the constants involved might be higher; there's a lot of overhead to hold an array of size N and also a doubly-linked list of size N.

---

### Hash-set

The time requirements for the other solutions are largely determined by their initialisation stages, which take O(N) time. Initialising an empty hash-set, on the other hand, is O(1). As before, we also initialise a variable holding a current minimum value to be 1.

- `processNext` is implemented by inserting the number into the set, in O(1) amortised time.
- `getSmallestNotSeen` updates the current minimum by incrementing it until it's no longer in the set, and then returns it. Membership tests on a hash-set are O(1), and the number of increments over all queries is limited by the number of times `processNext` is called, so this is also O(1) amortised time.

Asymptotically, this solution takes O(1) time for initialisation and queries, and it uses O(min(Q,N)) space where Q is the number of queries, while the other solutions use O(N) space regardless.

---

I think it should be straightforward to prove that O(min(Q,N)) space is asymptotically optimal, so the hash-set turns out to be the best option. Credit goes to [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2041077/dave) for combining the hash-set with a current-minimum variable to do `getSmallestNotSeen` in O(1) amortised time.

Comment: For Hash-set, iterate starting at the prior min for amortized constant time.

Comment: Good call, this actually makes the hash-set competitive even for large Q.